# Using programming language C to model a linear chain of atomic oscillators (atoms connected by series of springs)

Tags: c

This    question    involves    using   the programming language    C   to  model   a   linear  chain   of  atomic
oscillators.    I’ve    included    my  work    on  this    so  far on  the next    few pages.  But basically,  N   #   of
atoms   are connected   in  a   straight    line    by  a   series  of  springs (I’ve   drawn   a   picture on  the next
page).  The two ends    can be  thought of  as  walls.  The equation    of  motion  that    governs each    atom
in  this    chain   can be  derived to  get the following
A(t)    – k/m   *   [   x(i-1)  – 2x(i) +   x(i+1)  ]   =   0
Where   1   <=  i   <   =   N   and the equations   are coupled.    Here,   k   is  the spring  force.
So, there   exists  a   system  of  second  order,  coupled differential    equations   (one    for each    atom    in
the chain). 
The question    is  to  use the programming language    C   to  model   the behavior    of  these   atomic
oscillators.
Specifically,   my  teacher wants   me  to  use Verlet  integration as  follows
This    question    involves    using   the programming language    C   to  model   a   linear  chain   of  atomic
oscillators.    I’ve    included    my  work    on  this    so  far on  the next    few pages.  But basically,  N   #   of
atoms   are connected   in  a   straight    line    by  a   series  of  springs (I’ve   drawn   a   picture on  the next
page).  The two ends    can be  thought of  as  walls.

Here    is  the given   data:
(1) A   force   is  applied to  the first   atom    in  the chain   that    affects the rest    of  the atoms   in  the 
chain
(2) Thus,   there   exists  an  initial velocity    (choose an  initial velocity    that    makes   sense   at  the 
atomic  level)
(3) Choose  a   delta   time    that    allows  us  to  see the behavior    of  the atoms   (~  10^-14  sec).
(4) Use the Verlet  integration algorithm   to  find    the position    and velocity    of  each    atom    in  the 
chain   for a   given   time    (essentially    modeling    the behavior    of  the atoms).
(5) *Choose a   spring  force   that    would   properly    model   the interaction of  atoms.
(6) *Let    m = mass    be  the mass    of  an  atom.   Choose  this    mass.
This    is  all to  be  done    using   C.

Specifically,   my  teacher wants   me  to  use Verlet  integration as  follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfDgM.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7r5Y.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekWO2.jpg

Comment: You always have to include your work / effort along with the question!

Comment: have we seen this before - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538013/c-program-model-of-atomic-oscillator#comment82032910_4753801

Comment: Sure, you can do it. Just like you can model any harmonic oscillator (damped, resonate, etc.) in any programming language. Your question is more about numerical integration (e.g. "How do I do Verlet integration?") than what a language is capable of. I haven't looked at what Verlet integration is, but in the end, you essentially end up taking a Reimann sum approach with your modeled width for each rectangle (or trapezoid) sufficiently small to get a good approximation.

Comment: You can't do much better than [Wikipedia - Verlet Integration 1.4 A simple example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#A_simple_example)

Comment: Thanks David. Let me go through the link and try to come up with a break down of the verlet integration so that I may implement it.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi I have attached an images below. The last two images show a breakdown of my initial approach.
Thanks

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The link proved to be informative. I am trying to come up with a pseudocode from the java applet given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a physical simulation you need to store the state for current time T and use this to compute a new state at time T + \delta T. Then repeat until T reaches the desired end time. For some very simple problems, you can get away with storing just the current state and update it on the fly. But this problem is more easily done with 2 states. Let's call them C and N for the current T and next T+\delta T states respectively.  The basic algorithm is

```
Store initial conditions in N. For starters: N.t = 0
Emit N as output.
while (N.t < end of simulated time) {
  Copy N to C
  Use C to compute N // N.t = C.t + delta_t and do Verlet integration...
  Emit N as output.
}
```

You can get fancy with pointers to avoid the copy operation. But I gather you're a new C programmer. Don't go there yet.

The states can consist of arrays to hold the positions (x coordinates) of the atoms, their velocities, and accelerations.  I suggest you declare these as struct fields:

```
#define MAX_ATOM_COUNT (20) // or whatever, but don't make much bigger than needed
typedef struct state_s {
  double t; // Time of this state
  int n_atoms; // Actual number of atoms must be <= MAX_ATOM_COUNT.
  double x[MAX_ATOM_COUNT]; // position
  double v[MAX_ATOM_COUNT]; // velocity
  double a[MAX_ATOM_COUNT]; // acceleration
} STATE;
```

The advantage of structs is that you can do the copy operation of the algorithm with one statement:

```
STATE current, next;

next.t = 0;
...
while (next.t < SIMULATION_END_TIME) {
  current = next;
  ...
```

You get to do the rest.

Comment: This is really helpful Gene
I have been trying to come up with the concept but have had no success. Your answer has provided wonderful insight.
Let me do the rest and will come back for guidance.
Thanks.

Comment: If you run into problems see: [Verlet Method U.Delaware](http://www.physics.udel.edu/~bnikolic/teaching/phys660/numerical_ode/node5.html) and [Numerical Recipes - Second-Order Conservative Equations (requires flash)](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html#pg=928)

Answer (score 0):

I am new in C, I tried to follow up on your concept but I could not go past the idea. I came up with a little code but it's full of errors. Hope you can advise.
Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<math.h>
//#define MAX_ATOM_COUNT (20)

 // 
typedef struct state_s{
double t; // Time of this state
int n_atoms; 
/* Actual number of atoms must be <= 
* MAX_ATOM_COUNT
*/
double x[MAX_ATOM_COUNT]; // position
double v[MAX_ATOM_COUNT]; //velocity
double a[MAX_ATOM_COUNT]; // acceleration
}STATE;

void main()
{

/*
* Let the current initial conditions be c
* Let the next condition be n
* Let the MAX_ATOM_COUNT be user specified
* 
*/
double t, MAX_ATOM_COUNT;
double SIMULATION_END_TIME;
double c, n;
int gd = DETECT, gm;
initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\tc\\bgi");
//Path for graphics drivers

line(100, 200, 150, 200);

arc(200, 200, 0, 180, 50);
arc(260, 200, 0, 180, 50);
arc(230, 200, 180, 360, 20);

arc(320, 200, 0, 180, 50);
arc(290, 200, 180, 360, 20);

arc(380, 200, 0, 180, 50);
arc(350, 200, 180, 360, 20);

line(430, 200, 470, 200);

getch();
closegraph();

//Value of simulation end time
printf(" Enter the value of simulation duration\n");
scanf("%d", &SIMULATION_END_TIME);

// Store initial conditions in N
printf("Enter the Maximum atom count\n");
scanf("%d", &MAX_ATOM_COUNT);

printf("Enter the current initial conditions\n");
scanf("%d", &c);

printf("Enter the next conditions\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

while (t < SIMULATION_END_TIME) {
c = n;
n * t = c * t + delta_t;

// Do verlet Integration Computation
x1 = x0 + (x0 - x1) + a*pow(dt, 2);

printf("%d", &n);
}


STATE current, next;

next.t = 0;

while (next.t < SIMULATION_END_TIME) {
c = n;
}

printf("The position is:\n");
printf("%d", &x);

printf("The velocity is:\n");
printf("%d", &v);

printf("The acceleration is:\n");
printf("%d", &a);

}
```